# Trying to find all collections in an object not null with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to build a generic unit test method, to make sure all of our objects are initiliazing their properties that are collections on the constructor. I instead of manually checking with assert on each property, and then thinking ahaed if a class object is modified, I wanted to use reflection. The problem is that the collections, and not just List, but a class copy of the class, and then inherit List.

So, we may have somthing like the following:

```
public class PaymentType
{
   int Id{get;set;}
   PaymentTypeCollection PaymentTypeCollection {get;set;}

}

public class PaymentTypeCollection : List<PaymentType>
{
   //som ecustom stuff here

}
```

Now the problem is that when you itterate over the properties of the object from class PaymentType, and try to do a reflection method with the following check, it comes back false, and understandably.

```
foreach (var prop in objectType.GetProperties())
        {
            // test if property is IEnumerable<T>? This comes back as false
            if (typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
            {
               //do stuff here
            }
        }
```

How could I go about the issue. I need to see if the property, is then inheriting IEnumerable? Since the type would actually be PaymentTypeColelction. How would I handle that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing generics: A "master-type" IEnumerable<> that is generic, but matches all specific types (IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<object>, ...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993408/comparing-generics-a-master-type-ienumerable-that-is-generic-but-matches-a) (Actually, [this one's probably better, whoops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/982487/382780).)

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-generic `IEnumerable`. The generic `IEnumerable<out T>` implements `IEnumerable`, and you don't have to worry about type arguments.

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

But be careful, for example `string` also implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so your method will also find `string` properties.

Comment: I ran into that just now, with the string issue.  Lol  Thanks. Yea, it is to do PreLoad on the collections, but was throwing me off on how to check it this way.